# Hook up the key down in TextBox (MVVM)

Tags: wpf, mvvm, binding, triggers, command

Have a little problem with hooking up the keydown event without codebehind! 
So, we have the combobox

```
<ComboBox Height="20" Width="auto"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding AlignComboItems}"
                  SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedComboItem, Mode=TwoWay}"
                  SelectedValuePath="Key" DisplayMemberPath="Value"

                  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}"
                  x:Name="cmbBoxAlign">
</ComboBox>
```

and some TextBox.

```
<TextBox Text={Binding SomeSource}></TextBox>
```

How to catch the keydown event on the TextBox for selecting the (for example) the last element in ComboBox? I cant use the TextBox DataSource property changing, because need hook the user input up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't mind installing the Expression Blend SDK you should be able to do this in your textbox

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="KeyUp">
        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Path=TheCommand}" />
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

After adding a reference to `System.Windows.Interactivity` and the following namespace in your xaml

```
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
```

Link to the Expression SDK for 4.0

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=10801

Comment: In addition, there are plenty of MVVM frameworks out there with their own takes on this, which if any are you using?

Comment: Thanks, I think this is the easiest way.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have code fire in your view model every time there is a key down in the text box you need to change the binding slightly:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding SomeSource, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

Then in the view model the setter will be called:

```
private string _someSource;
public string SomeSource{
  get { return _someSource; }
  set { 
    //this will fire on key down
    _someSource= value;
    //based off the value you can set SelectedComboItem accordingly
    OnPropertyChanged( "SomeSource" );
  }
}
```

Also, make sure you have INotifyPropertyChanged set up on your view model.

Comment: In this way it will be changing all times, even the DataSource was changed programmatically not by user!

Comment: Ah I see, I didn't understand that from you question.  Yes this would fire even when the value is changed programmatically.

Comment: I need it fires just when user type smth)